# Imwheel script without GUI

Tags: bash, scripts, startup, mouse-scroll

Currently I have this script set to be initiated on startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Version 0.1 Tuesday, 07 May 2013
# Comments and complaints http://www.nicknorton.net
# GUI for mouse wheel speed using imwheel in Gnome
# imwheel needs to be installed for this script to work
# sudo apt-get install imwheel
# Pretty much hard wired to only use a mouse with
# left, right and wheel in the middle.
# If you have a mouse with complications or special needs,
# use the command xev to find what your wheel does.
#
### see if imwheel config exists, if not create it ###
if [ ! -f ~/.imwheelrc ]
then

cat >~/.imwheelrc<<EOF
".*"
None, Up, Button4, 1
None, Down, Button5, 1
Control_L, Up, Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L, Up, Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L, Down, Shift_L|Button5
EOF

fi
##########################################################

CURRENT_VALUE=$(awk -F 'Button4,' '{print $2}' ~/.imwheelrc)

NEW_VALUE=$(zenity --scale --window-icon=info --ok-label=Apply --title="Wheelies" --text "Mouse wheel speed:" --min-value=1 --max-value=100 --value="$CURRENT_VALUE" --step 1)

if [ "$NEW_VALUE" == "" ];
then exit 0
fi

sed -i "s/\($TARGET_KEY *Button4, *\).*/\1$NEW_VALUE/" ~/.imwheelrc # find the string Button4, and write new value.
sed -i "s/\($TARGET_KEY *Button5, *\).*/\1$NEW_VALUE/" ~/.imwheelrc # find the string Button5, and write new value.

cat ~/.imwheelrc
imwheel -kill
```

That's what it looks like when executed:

[image: script gui]

Now the question is how would I go about making this script run without GUI, and always set the scroll speed to `2`?

Currently I have to click Apply every time I start the PC and I didn't write the script myself so I don't know how to go about changing it.

Comment: Would it not be more efficient to ask how to set the scroll speed to 2? The answer is in `~/.imwheelrc` by the way so include that ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind but when I set the .imwheelrc to '2' it resets to default every time I restart the computer. Is there a way to make the change permanent?

Comment: Add `imwheel` somewhere during boot or in startup apps(?)

Comment: @Rinzwind Great, I deleted the original script, added imwheel to startup and manually changed the .imwheelrc  file to 2 (Button 4, Button 5), and It works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Make it an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Rinzwind in the comment section I managed to solve the problem by deleting the original script, adding `imwheel` to startup programs and manually changing the ~/.imwheelrc file.

from:

```
".*"
None, Up, Button4,
None, Down, Button5,
Control_L, Up, Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L, Up, Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L, Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

to:

```
".*"
None, Up, Button4, 2
None, Down, Button5, 2
Control_L, Up, Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L, Up, Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L, Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

Where `2` represents the scroll speed.